# Perform action pressing notification Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase notification in order to send and receive RemoteNotification.

When I receive a notification, I receive also an ID that let me to identify a specifically "post".

Now, when I click on notification, I need that app to open a viewController passing it the received ID, in order to start a method (in `viewDidLoad()`) that load "post" informations.

this is the code of notification:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // Print message ID.
    print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

    let aps = userInfo["aps"] as! NSDictionary
    let body_notifica = aps["alert"]! as! NSDictionary
    let titolo_notifica = body_notifica["title"]! as! String
    let testo_notifica = body_notifica["body"]! as! String

    let id_lavoro = userInfo["id_lavoro"]! //THIS IS THE ID I NEED TO PASS TO VIEW CONTROLLER

    if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.inactive || application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.background{
        let viewController = self.window!.rootViewController!.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "annuncio_view_controler")
        viewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "a", sender: <#T##Any?#>)
    }


    let banner = Banner(title: titolo_notifica, subtitle: testo_notifica, image: UIImage(named: "Info"), backgroundColor: UIColor(red:0.0/255.0, green:0.0/255.0, blue:0.0/255.0, alpha:0.5))
    banner.dismissesOnTap = true
    banner.show(duration: 3.0)

    print(userInfo)

}
```

thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

you can handle this by using this example of code

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {


    if ( application.applicationState == .inactive || application.applicationState == .background){

        //handle tapping on push notification and here you can open needed controller
    }
}
```

to know exactly which controller you need to open need to see on controllers hierarchy

in my case its

```
   `guard let rootViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as? TabBarVC else {
        return
    }
    // select second tab
    rootViewController.selectedIndex = 1

    guard let navigationController = rootViewController.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController else {
        return
    }
```

`

**EDIT**: I tried with this, but nothing.

```
if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.inactive || application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.background{
        let viewController = self.window!.rootViewController!.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "home_view_controller") as! HomeViewController

        viewController.toPassId = id_lavoro!
        viewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue_annuncio_profilo", sender: self)

    }
```

How can I check hierarchy? My view is not a view of TabBar, it can be open from a lot of view (that stay also in TabBar)

Comment: ok. but how can I set the ID to that view? I need a similar of "prepare(for: segue)...

Comment: `viewController.your_id = id_lavoro`

Comment: if you run your code what happens   `let viewController = self.window!.rootViewController!.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "home_view_controller") as! HomeViewController

        viewController.toPassId = id_lavoro!
        viewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue_annuncio_profilo", sender: self)`

Comment: not understand what you doing, why performSegue?? why not push or present?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Vadim Kozak

```
 if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.inactive || application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.background{
        guard let rootViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController else {
            return
        }
        // select second tab
        rootViewController.selectedIndex = 1

        guard let navigationController = rootViewController.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController else {
            return
        }


        let viewController = self.window!.rootViewController!.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "annuncio_view_controler") as! LavoroViewController

        viewController.id_lavoro = id_lavoro!

        rootViewController.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }
```